# search database for relevant fields

Tags: php, search, mysqli

I need a way to say something like

```
Mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id.contains('SOME STRING')")
```

What i need it to do exactly is retrieve all fields that are relevant.

Comment: What you really "need", is => [**"this"**](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html) **and** [**"this"**](http://docs.php.net/manual/da/mysqli.query.php) <= *"GIVE a man a fish, you will feed him for a day. SHOW a man HOW to fish, you will feed him for a lifetime"*.

Comment: visit http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_where.asp.
You can find an answer here

Answer (score 0):

i think i might have thought up a solution to this, if anyone else is curious, take the string and create a search for array elements.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe SQL LIKE query?

```
Mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id LIKE '%SOME STRING%'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$hresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM   `database_name`.`table_name` WHERE `table_name`.`column_name1` = 'variable' AND `table_name`.`column_name2` = 'variable2'");


while($hrow=mysql_fetch_array($hresult)){
    $new_variable= $hrow['column_name'];//

$new_variable2= $hrow['column_name'];//

}
```